# How do console games avoid port forwarding with user hosted servers?

Tags: networking, multiplayer

On AAA xbox games (Call of duty, etc.), the company acts as a matchmaking service but the users host all of the games. Because not everyone has ports forwarded on their router, how do these games create an accessible server without relying on port forwarding?

In other words, how would one (on a high level) implement NAT to NAT connections?

The only thing I can think of is:

1. Try to open up a port via UPNP
2. If that fails, use a centralized relay server (latency!) or host on the centralized server

Is that a suitable idea or is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called NAT punchthrough. Today costs of dedicated servers are so low (and advantages of having it are so much better) almost nobody uses it.
When you're behind NAT your router will forward packets from outside to you only if you initiated communication first, so router has mapped that outside IP and random port to your computer.

Solution: basically when user hosts (P2P hosting) a game, all clients (all games) start sending packets to host and host sends packets to them, so hosts opens up to packets from outside after few tries. It's actually more complicated then that, here's what [RakNet's documation on NAT punchtrough](http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/natpunchthrough.html) says:

> NAT Punchthrough Algorithm
>       Peer P1 wants to connect to peer P2, both of whom are connected to a third Non-NAT system, F
>
> Peer P1 calls OpenNAT() with the RakNetGUID (unique identifier) of P2 to F.
>
> F returns failure if P2 is not connected, or already attempting punchthrough to P1.
>
> F remembers busy state of P1 and P2. If either P1 or P2 is busy, the request is pushed to a queue. Otherwise F requests most recently used external port from P1 and P2. P1 and P2 are flagged as busy.
>
> If either P1 or P2 do not respond punchthrough fails with ID_NAT_TARGET_UNRESPONSIVE and the busy flag is unset. Otherwise, F sends timestamped connection message to P1 and P2 simultaneously.
>
> P1 and P2 act identically at this point. First, they send multiple UDP datagrams to each other's internal LAN addresses. They then try each other's external IP/port as seen by F. Ports are attempted sequentially, up to MAX_PREDICTIVE_PORT_RANGE.
>
> If at any point a datagram arrives from the remote peer, we enter state PUNCHING_FIXED_PORT. Datagrams are only sent to that IP/port combination the remainder of the algorithm. If our reply arrives on the remote system, the NAT is considered bidirectional and ID_NAT_PUNCHTHROUGH_SUCCEEDED is returned to the user.
>
> When NAT is open, or if we exhaust all ports, P1 and P2 send to F that they are ready for a new punchthrough attempt.